# Jquery mobile - CSS - textarea take up full width

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, textarea

I have two divs. One should take up 75% of the space, and the other takes up 25%. The smaller div contains a button. The largest div contains a textarea. I'm having issues with getting the textarea take up the entire space though. The `ui-block-a` div is taking up the correct 75%. But the textarea won't fill the entire div. I set the `right-margin:0;` and `width:100%;`, but nothing happens.

```
 <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:75%"><textarea placeholder="What's happening?" style="width: 100%; margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto; margin-right: 0px; height: 52px;" class="ui-input-text ui-shadow-inset ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-textinput-autogrow"></textarea></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:25%"><input type="button" class="ui-btn" value="Submit"></div>
    </div>
```

How it looks

[image]

When looking via developer tools, I notice there is a margin to the right of the textarea.
[image]

tl;dr - Need to get rid off the orange part (margin). Setting `margin:0;width:100%;`  doesn't work.